# Homebrew Symlink Error

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to install memcached using:

```
brew install memcached
```

This ends in error about homebrew not being able to create a symlink:

```
The linking step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
```

Help!

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I uninstalled what homebrew had so far installed (libevent dependency):

```
brew uninstall libevent
```

Then chow-ned the usr/local directory:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

Then tried to install memcached again and it worked:

```
brew install memcached
```

Comment: Saved me from my nightmare! THANKS!

Comment: still works! Note the septerr needs to change to your username

Comment: When trying to "brew install memcached", you get the following error:
Not working: curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found. Error: Failed to download resource "libevent"
Download failed: https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/levent/libevent/libevent-2.0/libevent-2.0.22-stable.tar.gz

Comment: Can you @JasonDScott  explain what exactly these commands do?

Comment: @akshayrajkore `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` recursively changes ownership of the directory so that your user does not need admin permissions to write to that folder or any files it contains, which is where brew is trying to write to.

Comment: your chown command is no longer supported in High Sierra. Use 
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`instead

Comment: chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 100):

As of High Sierra, /usr/local is no longer chown-able. The new procedure suggested in [a Homebrew issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228) is:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

FYI: If required /usr/local subfolders (e.g. ./include or ./Frameworks) are missing, you'll have to mkdir them first

Comment: I get `chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted`

Comment: I tried this in MacOS Mojave v10.14.6 and it worked

Comment: Using chmod to add permissions is a better solution than changing the owner -- especially if you have more than one user account on your Mac.

Answer (score 25):

Thanks for updating your own question this helped me a lot.  I fixed this issue by making all locations in `/usr/local` writable to group as I am already in the admin group.

To do this just use the following command

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local
```

Comment: and then of course doing brew link memcached after this step.

Answer (score 7):

after i performed the suggestions in @septerr answer, i still was unable to install carthage via homebrew... after some googleing i found this: Gist https://gist.github.com/dalegaspi/7d336944041f31466c0f9c7a17f7d601

Anyway... got this:

`Error: An unexpected error occurred during the 'brew link' step The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks`

did this:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

and

`sudo install -d -o $(whoami) -g admin /usr/local/Frameworks`

after that is was able to install carthage successfully

Answer (score 3):

It seems that since El Capitan the file permissions in /usr/local have been changed, causing the above problem for me.

Instead of the chosen solution I suggest to do a:

```
sudo chown -R :staff /usr/local
```

This will work for all users

Answer (score 1):

Symlink errors prevented

`brew install pyenv`

on macOS Big Sur 11.6.2.

Solution suggested by @sean-denigris worked

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

Before this I had tried the solution proposed by @marko

`sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local`

that gave the following error

`chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local: Operation not permitted`