# Problem installing MySQL-Python on Mac OS 10.14.1

Tags: pip, mysql-python, macos-mojave

I recently upgraded to Mac OS Mojave and now can't install MySQL-Python:

```
pip install MySQL-Python

...
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.so
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

The stack trace says that the "ssl" library wasn't found. I'm not sure what that means though as I have the latest XCode and OpenSSL is installed. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on MacOS 10.14, and I was able to solve it using these steps:

Change permissions for `/usr/local` to [allow Homebrew to create links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47228630/5194377):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Re-install openssl now that permissions have been fixed:

```
brew reinstall openssl
```

Run these two commands to allow compilers to find openssl:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Then, try again to install MySQL-Python:

```
pip install MySQL-Python
```

Answer (score 1):

> Change permissions for /usr/local to allow Homebrew to create links:
>
> ```
> sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
> ```
>
> Re-install openssl now that permissions have been fixed:
>
> ```
> brew reinstall openssl
> ```
>
> Run these two commands to allow compilers to find openssl:
>
> ```
> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
> ```
>
> Then, try again to install MySQL-Python:
>
> ```
> pip install MySQL-Python
> ```

It works for Mac 10.14.2 with python2.7 /Django 1.9.8 and mysql-server 8 with mysql-clinet;

Comment: As of 2019, this is the only valid solution which works on a mac. Other answers on SO which suggest link/unlink of mysql c connector simply dont work. Thanks!